# How to properly render vue with prefetched data for SSR?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I tried following the example from this [page](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#data-store) by prefetching a github user from API and then render the page, however, I'm getting a message `Cannot find element: #app`

This only happens when I try to add a context in my code

```
import { createApp } from './app'
import { createRouter } from './router';
import { createStore } from './store'

export default context => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { app, router, store } = createApp()

    router.push(context.url)

    router.onReady(() => {
      const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents();

      if (!matchedComponents.length) {
        return reject({ code: 404 });
      }

      // This `rendered` hook is called when the app has finished rendering
      context.rendered = () => {
        // After the app is rendered, our store is now
        // filled with the state from our components.
        // When we attach the state to the context, and the `template` option
        // is used for the renderer, the state will automatically be
        // serialized and injected into the HTML as `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`.
        context.state = store.state
      }

      resolve(app)
    }, reject)
  })
  .then(app => {
    renderVueComponentToString(app, (err, res) => {
      print(res);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    print(err);
  });
}
```

However, rendering my code using the code below introduces a different error message `The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  router.push(url);
  router.onReady(() => {
    const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents();
    if (!matchedComponents.length) {
      return reject({ code: 404 });
    }
    resolve(app);
  }, reject);
})
  .then(app => {
    renderVueComponentToString(app, (err, res) => {
      print(res);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    print(err);
  });
```

Fod additional info
**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'about' }">About</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'contact' }">Contact</router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                title: 'Welcome To My Site'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**entry-client.js**

```
import app from './app'
import { createStore } from './store'

let store = createStore();

if (window.__INITIAL_STATE__) {
  // We initialize the store state with the data injected from the server
  store.replaceState(window.__INITIAL_STATE__)
}

app.$mount('#app', true);
```

Comment: Do you have a `div` with `id="app"` in your `App.vue`?

Comment: @ÖzgürUysal Yeah, I do have it. I'm not really sure why that's happening.

Comment: You don't have an `app` instance in your `entry-server.js` unless it's on top of the code as in your `entry-client.js`. Note that you shouldn't just import the `app` like a client side app.  In SSR each request should create a separate `app` instance to avoid cross-request state pollution. See how `createApp` function is used. https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html#code-structure-with-webpack. I'd recommend you to review https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0.

Comment: @ÖzgürUysal Updated the code but to no avail. I think `renderVueComponentToString` is not being called when exporting context.